# Rails validation with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this:

```
class Calendar < ApplicationRecord
  validates :number_of_teams, presence: true, if: :even_and_small?
  has_many :matches
  has_many :days
  belongs_to :championship

  def even_and_small?
    number_of_teams <= 20 && 
    number_of_teams % 2 == 0
  end
```

I want to validate the `number_of_teams` attribute only when it's below 20 and an even number. But when I try it out on irb:

```
2.7.0 :004 > c.championship_id = 1
2.7.0 :005 > c.number_of_teams = 33
2.7.0 :006 > c.valid?
  Championship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "championships".* FROM "championships" WHERE "championships"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => true
```

Validation happens even when conditions are not met. What am I missing?

Comment: `Validation happens even when conditions are not met` your code does not show this. I think you are confusing what the validation does: what you are saying there is `if the value is less than 20 and even, make sure it's not empty` which is always true since it has to be present to actually trigger the validation. And you are not adding a validation for any other case, so all the possible values for that field are either valid or not even validated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `validates_presence_of`

```
validates_presence_of :number_of_teams, if: :even_and_small?
```

[Relevant Rails API documentation for validates_presence_of](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of)

Answer (score 0):

```
  def even_and_small?
    # guard to bypass validation
    return if number_of_teams.nil? || number_of_teams > 20

    enter code here
    errors.add(:number_of_teams, :invalid) unless number_of_teams % 2 == 0
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#validate 
validates :even_and_small?

  # validation
  def even_and_small?
    errors.add(:number_of_teams, :not_present) if number_of_teams.nil?
    errors.add(:number_of_teams, :number_not_even) unless number_of_teams % 2 == 0
  end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a description to your code and how it answers the question.